# Copy down list elements to fill NA list elements

Tags: r, list

Below is the code I have now

```
set.seed(20)
test_list <- list("1" = matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10), 
                  "2" = NA, 
                  "3" = NA, 
                  "4" = NA, 
                  "5" = NA, 
                  "6" = matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10), 
                  "7" = NA, 
                  "8" = NA)
```

I would like to find a way to copy down the list elements that are not containing an NA with the prior elements contents so that each list element will be filled in. Element 1-5 will contain the matrix in element 1 and 6-8 will contain the matrix in element 6. I can setup this problem without using NAs as the elements which should be copied (if using NULL or something else like that helps the solution).

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` function with `accumulate` mode (may not work on very big data):

```
str(test_list)
#List of 8
# $ 1: num [1:10, 1:10] 1.163 -0.586 1.785 -1.333 -0.447 ...
# $ 2: logi NA
# $ 3: logi NA
# $ 4: logi NA
# $ 5: logi NA
# $ 6: num [1:10, 1:10] 0.548 -0.226 1.217 0.701 0.912 ...
# $ 7: logi NA
# $ 8: logi NA


fill_list <- Reduce(function(x, y) if(all(is.na(y))) x else y, test_list, acc = TRUE)

str(fill_list)
#List of 8
# $ : num [1:10, 1:10] 1.163 -0.586 1.785 -1.333 -0.447 ...
# $ : num [1:10, 1:10] 1.163 -0.586 1.785 -1.333 -0.447 ...
# $ : num [1:10, 1:10] 1.163 -0.586 1.785 -1.333 -0.447 ...
# $ : num [1:10, 1:10] 1.163 -0.586 1.785 -1.333 -0.447 ...
# $ : num [1:10, 1:10] 1.163 -0.586 1.785 -1.333 -0.447 ...
# $ : num [1:10, 1:10] 0.548 -0.226 1.217 0.701 0.912 ...
# $ : num [1:10, 1:10] 0.548 -0.226 1.217 0.701 0.912 ...
# $ : num [1:10, 1:10] 0.548 -0.226 1.217 0.701 0.912 ...
```

Comment: That was a really elegant solution, thank you. It works pretty fast for a couple of thousand elements at least.

Answer (score 5):

`is.na` can handle "list"s in, exactly, the way neeeded here: return `TRUE` in case of a *single* `NA`:

```
is.na(test_list)
#    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8 
#FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

This behaviour of `is.na`, also, makes testing on "list"s efficient as it avoids checking any elements with (length != 1).

Building a `NA` locf functionality off this:

```
cummax((!is.na(test_list)) * seq_along(test_list))
#1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
#1 1 1 1 1 6 6 6
```

we subset `test_list`:

```
test_list[cummax((!is.na(test_list)) * seq_along(test_list))]
```

Comment: This is quite delightful.  May need to reset the names though.

Comment: @RichScriven : ..wouldn't have thought usecases of a functionality that returns `c(TRUE, FALSE)` for `is.na(list(NA, c(NA, NA)))` .. :-). You 're right about the "names", I left it as is in case a printed info of which element was carried forward could be useful.